# Get method tuple from abbreviation in Brightway2

Tags: brightway

It is possible in Briwghtway2 to convert a method tuple into a string using `get_abbreviation()`, for example:

```
In  [1] Method(('IPCC 2013', 'climate change', 'GWP 100a')).get_abbreviation()  
Out [1] 'ipcc-2013cg.bd5af3f67229a1cc291b8ecb7f316fcf'
```

Is it possible to go back to the tuple from an abbreviation (i.e. de-abbreviate)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [abbreviate](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-data/src/aa5e4a8377aef097be0e694ead2a149ec04dec84/bw2data/ia_data_store.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#ia_data_store.py-11) function calculates the MD5 hash of the string of the method tuple. There isn't a general method to reverse hashes, and while there are [some](https://isc.sans.edu/tools/reversehash.html) [reverse](http://reversemd5.com/) MD5 rainbow tables, but they don't seem to have the string `bd5af3f67229a1cc291b8ecb7f316fcf`. So I think that unless you can find a list of possible method names and calculate their abbreviations, you are out of luck.

Comment: Disappointing but correct answer. For my needs, I'll generate and store a dictionary with `{method_tuple:method_abbreviation}` for all methods in my project.